# Use the paste command on file and save result to that same file

Tags: linux, unix

Basically I'm changing the carriage returns in my file using the paste command, but I'd like to save the result to that same file.

```
paste -s -d, filename1
```

I cannot install any tools like Sponge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use the `paste` command you will have to go for an approach like this one where you use a `tmp` file and you replace the original one **(take a backup of your file before doing this)**:

```
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat filename1 
abc
123
edf
xyz
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ paste -s -d, filename1 > filename2 && mv filename2 filename1
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat filename1 
abc,123,edf,xyz
```

**Notes:** The move operation will only take place if the `paste` ends up without error

If you are allowed to use other commands like `sed` then you can use the inline mode to modify directly the file without creating a tmp one.

```
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat filename1 
abc
123
edf
xyz
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ sed -i".bak" ':loop;N;$!bloop;s/\n/,/g' filename1 
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat filename1
abc,123,edf,xyz
XXX@XXX:~/Downloads/fun_play/archive/filestosearch$ cat filename1.bak 
abc
123
edf
xyz
```

**Notes:**

- `-i".bak"` allow you to modify the file and to take a backup file just in case, same file name and suffix `.bak`
- `':loop;N;$!bloop;s/\n/,/g'` create a label `loop`, add each line to the pattern buffer, when not reaching the last line, `go to` label `loop`, when you reach the last line you replace all the EOL (`\n`) by `,`.